# Which RMI exceptions indicate lost connections

Tags: java, rmi

I'm using the following bit of code to notify remote (RMI) event listeners of a change.

```
        // notify remote listeners of this change
        ThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {

            List<Integer> removal = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            listeners.getReadLock().lock();
            try {

                for (Entry<Integer, RemoteDataServerListener> e : listeners.entrySet()) {

                    try {
                        e.getValue().creditsChanged(player.getId(), player.getCredits());
                    } catch (RemoteException er) {

                        log.warn("Error in remote listener", er);

                        // this listener is gone
                        if (er instanceof NoSuchObjectException) {
                            log.info("Removing the listener");
                            removal.add(e.getKey());
                        }

                    }

                }

            } finally {
                listeners.getReadLock().unlock();
            }

            // listeners that are gone don't need future events
            listeners.removeAll(removal);


        }});
```

As you can see I remove a listener when it throws a `NoSuchObjectException`, but that's probably not the only exception that can be thrown.
Is there a complete list of RMI exceptions that indicate a remote object (or entire server) is lost/disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

That's a complicated question. Most of them don't indicate lost connections at all, in fact only UnmarshalException really does that, and only sometimes, e.g. when it wraps a ClassNotFoundException it doesn't indicate a lost connection.

In a sense ConnectIOException also indicates that, but it only happens when trying to revive a pooled client connection at the beginning of the call.

A more interesting and even more complex question is which exceptions preserve idempotence if you retry after them, and that is a very difficult question to answer. I devoted about 20 pages of my RMI book to that and I doubt that I covered every possibility.

NoSuchObjectException indicates that the remote object that exported the stub you are calling on is no longer there, i.e. has been unexported from its JVM.

RemoteException itself can mean practically anything, especially if you make the mistake of having your own application exceptions extend it. Don't do that. And in practice you shouldn't just catch RemoteException by itself, you should catch all the possible RMI exceptions separately with a catch-all RemoteException catcher at the bottom, as there are different recovery strategies for different exceptions. Unless you just want to give up on any remote error at all.

Comment: When is UnmarshalException thrown for other reasons than ClassnotFoundException? Anyway, yes, your third paragraph is the question at hand.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom (a) IOException, for example 'connection reset'; (b) NotSerializableException; (c) InvalidClassException; (d) OptionalDataException; (e) StreamCorruptedException; (f) InvalidObjectException; ..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you can ensure that your RMI application *always* throws back user defined or custom exceptions no matter what goes wrong at the server, catching `RemoteException` and removing the listener should be good to go. E.g.

```
public Object doSomething() throws RemoteException {
    Object o;
    try {
        // application processing
    } catch(final Throwable t) {
        throw new CustomException(t);
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't ensure that, nor can I ensure that an UnmarshalException will never be thrown because the client responds with an unknown object.

Comment: And unfortunately it isn't true anyway. Some remote exceptions indicate local problems, programming problems, etc., rather than connection issues.

Answer (score 0):

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/RemoteException.html it looks like I can treat all RemoteExceptions that way, except:

- UnmarshalException
- UnexpectedException
- ServerError

Comment: That conclusion is not correct and you cannot possibly reach it from anything on that page. java.rmi.ConnectException for example doesn't indicate a 'lost connection', it indicates a failure to create one in the first place.

Comment: @EJP A connection that cannot be created can also be seen as "lost", in a way, at least when determining whether the object can be discarded.

Comment: @EJP By the way I didn't really look at the main body of that page, but went (lightly) through the list of subclasses.

Comment: 'A connection that cannot be created can also be seen as "lost"': no it can't. It is a complety separate condition.

Comment: @EJP Well I did say "in a way". The point is, if I can't connect to a listener, I can safely discard it because retrying probably won't work.

Comment: The point is that the OP asked about 'lost connections'. A connection that wasn't created cannot be lost. The semantics are completely different. After a lost connection, the transaction may or may not have occurred and may or may not need retrying, depending on further detail of the exception: for example, a ServerError containing a MarshalException indicates that the transaction did occur but the server couldn't write the response. After a ConnectException, you definitely know that nothing whatsoever has happened at the server.  Conflating them serves no useful purpose.